# android monkey script for multiple devices

Tags: android, robotium, monkeyrunner, monkey

Can some body can help me for to put android monkey test for multiple devices ?

->adb shell monkey -p com.example -v 500000

So here i have connected 10 devices in my PC. I wanted to run monkey test for all the device and capture the logs at the same time.

Can any one suggest me on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

for s in s1 s2 s3
do
    adb -s $s shell monkey -p com.example -v 500000 > $s.log
done
```

where s1, s2, ... are the serial number of your devices