# Can i run monkey run without connecting with pc?

Tags: android

I just want to run monkey run on multiple devices without connecting to pc as i need real time user scenario. And also i want to save logs on sdcard. Is it possible? I can give my best to complete if chances are there

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22633217/2982225)

Comment: Issue the monkey command from the adb shell via command line, once monkey starts executing on the device, disconnect the device

Comment: For starting on multiple devices, check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20006551/2982225)